# Materialize Navbar : How to display the same navbar links in mobile device with sidebar

Tags: html, css, material-design, navbar

I am trying material css to create navbar links but what i have read so far i have to write separate code (html markup) for mobile device why it's like that.

My question is why i need to repeat the same 'navbar links' two time If i want to display the same navbar links in mobile device.

```
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: One option is to move things to a self contained component, so you provide the links as an @Input() and then loop through them to add to your form.

Comment: these are simple 'static links' as you could observe through attached picture.

Comment: Yes, but moving them into a component makes the replication not as complex to change, testable etc.  In the current navigator, you need to list them twice in the component you are referring to.

Comment: without listing them twice, is there no other way!.. Links are coming dynamically if i list them twice then same i have to do for the backend. it would not be best practice.

Comment: I am not aware of another way, as the component you are using, and I have used, has the double entries. Maybe there is a 3rd party component that hides this.  That is why I suggest a component with the service, as it will be a single occurrence, and share this information into the two spots, since you simply embed the component there.  The HTML has the 2 lines (1 for each section with the component) and no other code is doubled.

Comment: yes you are right, here i am displaying html (static) links but links will come dynamically from C# because i think if i could sort out this in html then dynamic links also i could handle in the same way. thanks for your comments.